# Lend and borrow

Tags: word-usage

I would like to know if these two sentences are correct:

A) Could you lend your calculator for me? I left my at home

B) Could you borrow the calculator from someone else? I can't lend you mine.

Or should I say in letter "A": Could you **lend me your calculator** ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following sounds right to me.

> A: Could you lend me your calculator? I left **mine** at home. 
>   B: Could you borrow *it* from someone else? I can't lend you mine.

In B, there's nothing wrong *per se* in using the word *calculator* again, but since it has already been referred to previously in the conversation, you could use the pronoun "it" in its place.

Depending on the scenario, the response could include an apology (**Sorry**, I can't lend you mine.), but it isn't strictly necessary for correctness.

Answer (score 7):

A is incorrect. B is fine.

Here is how you could fix it,

> Could you lend your calculator **to** me? I left **mine** at home.

or

> Could you lend **me** your calculator? ...

*Practical English Grammar* by Michael Swan, explains **borrow** and **lend** like this,

> **109 borrow and lend**
>   **Borrowing** is **taking** (for a time).
>     *Can I **borrow** your bicycle?* (NOT <del>*Can I lend your bicycle?*</del>)
>   You borrow something **from** somebody.
>     *I **borrowed** a pound **from** my brother.* (NOT <del>*I borrowed my brother a pound.*</del>)
>   **Lending** (AmE also *loaning*) is **giving** (for a time). You lend something **to** somebody, or **lend somebody** something.
>     *I **lent** my coat **to** Steve, and I never saw it again.*
>     ***Lend me*** your comb for a minute, will you? (NOT <del>*Borrow me your ...*</del>)

Comment: I haven't realize that "for"is wrong too. Thanks!

Comment: It (*lend that for me*) might not be wrong per se. But it would mean something else. It would be understood as you wouldn't want to lend that thing by yourself, so you asked someone else to do that for you instead.